# How to update HTML body param in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php file as the main page. home.php. In this file I have used some codes like this. Body params.

```
<body user="<?php echo $_SESSION["LOGGED_USER"] ?>" status="<?php echo $_SESSION["STATUS"] ?>">
```

So when user logged in, this appears in the body tags. And i can take those values anytime. Now I need to change those values in runtime. I mean when user change the user email, i need to change that using javascript. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.attr( attributeName, value )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2)

> Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

```
$('body').attr('user', newValue)
```

Using native [`.setAttribute(attributeName, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

> Adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute on the specified element. Returns undefined.

```
document.querySelector("body").setAttribute("user", "newValue")
```

**Note:** However to store arbitrary data, I would recommend you to use `data-*` prefixed custom attributes.

Comment: How can I use those 'data-*' prefix custom attributes ? Example please

Comment: @ChanakaDeSilva, Just like other attibutes like `$('body').attr('data-user', newValue)`